# Reception of Low Power Mode disabled notification in iOS

Tags: ios, background

I am trying to follow the iOS energy guide and make my app low-power mode aware; to this end I am following the guide posted [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html), which provides the code on how to subscribe to this type of events. I have implemented this function as is shown below:

```swift
  /// Function to subscribe to low-power mode events
  ///
  func subscribeToLowBatteryNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                        selector: #selector(lowBatteryHandle),
                        name: Notification.Name.NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChange,
                        object: nil)
  }

  /// handler for low-power mode events.
  ///
  @objc func lowBatteryHandle(_ notification: Notification) {
    let lowPowerModeEnabled = ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled

    if lowPowerModeEnabled {
      stopTrackingBackground()
    } else {
      startTrackingBackground()
    }
  }
```

This is pretty straightforward. Then I put my app in the background while continuously tracking the location as needed; then I enable low power mode and the notification
is indeed received (in the background) successfully prompting the app to suspend tracking. Unfortunately, when low-power is *disabled* and I expect to receive a similar event for the status change (while in the background) this is not received in the background and the event is only delivered to the app when I enter the app again. Does anyone know how to receive these events in the background?

Answer (score 0):

When your app discontinues the background tracking, the system moves to [suspend the application](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3). While suspended your app won't receive notifications, even about the state of low power mode. One strategy might be to move to a lower level of location delivery frequency, such as [significant location changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati), or using the [deferred location](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW14) updates as may or may not be appropriate for your use case.

> When a user disables the Background App Refresh setting either globally or for your app, the significant-change location service doesn’t relaunch your app. Further, while Background App Refresh is off an app doesn’t receive significant-change or region monitoring events even when it's in the foreground.

Since low power mode disables background app refresh globally, I think this means significant-change events probably won't be delivered. The note says "When a **user** disables", but it doesn't say whether the means a primary action or secondary, in the case of low power mode. [Deferred location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423830-deferredlocationupdatesavailable) updates will be available, however.

Apple provides other guidance, in the docs on [automatically pausing location updates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620553-pauseslocationupdatesautomatical)

> For apps that have in-use authorization, a pause to location updates ends access to location changes until the app is launched again and able to restart those updates. If you do not wish location updates to stop entirely, consider disabling this property and changing location accuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers when your app moves to the background. Doing so allows you to continue receiving location updates in a power-friendly manner.

Also, in the documentation for the [standard location service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service), apple provides more guidance

> To minimize power consumption, never set the desiredAccuracy property to a higher accuracy than what you actually need. Similarly, always set the distanceFilter property to the greatest value that meets the needs of your app. The system always tries to give you the best location data that is available, but these properties give the system the flexibility to turn off hardware elements when they are not needed.

All of this information suggests that to continue receiving updates while low power mode is enabled, you must use the standard service or the deferred service. To be power friendly while the standard service is enabled, you can potentially reconfigure your manager to deliver fewer updates by adjusting the `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` properties.

Comment: are you sure these are allowed in low-power mode and won't end up killing the application as well?

Comment: @jtimz Good point, as with all apple docs, the information is there but sometimes you have to track it down. I updated my answer with more evidence from the docs.

Comment: thanks for the thorough reply; I've played around quite a bit with these filters but when not in low-power mode I do need quite good accuracy (within 100 meters). Also I think you need to restart location tracking manager in order for the new settings to be applied; by doing that I am risking killing the application, am I wrong?

Comment: I think if you do it within the notification handler, you wouldn't be at risk. I'm making an assumption that the notification handlers are all finished before suspending an app. But I don't have anything to back that up. You might also find [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html) helpful, if you hadn't seen it already.

Comment: yep, I've seen this but on some iPhones that my app is deployed it gets suspended and from what the logs and users tells me correlates highly with low-power mode being active. Also I want to make the app behaves better in this situation but without risking killing it in the process... but as you said, Apple documentation is a bit vague on the subject -- hence the question.

Comment: Background execution always leads to these questions in iOS. It's both helpful for users and challenging for developers. I hope you find a combination of technologies that work for you use case.